# How to draw database structure with Perl?

Tags: perl, dbi

I know that is possible to load database structure and automatically create `Result/*.pm` files for usage with DBIx::Class. Also I know that it is possible to draw an image of all tables at this database and their relationship. But I do not know exactly modules which do this.

May you please remember me the modules to do these two tasks?
Thank you.

Comment: DBI's database handles have methods that provide all the necessary info.

Comment: See https://metacpan.org/pod/GraphViz::DBI::General

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dump your database to schema files with [dbicdump](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader/view/script/dbicdump).

For the diagram try [SQL::Translator::Producer::Diagram](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Translator::Producer::Diagram) with [SQL::Translator::Parser::DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/SQL::Translator::Parser::DBIx::Class).